# I need to print this pascal triangle but without the comma into between the different array elements. How do I get rid of the commas

Tags: python, arrays, pascal

```
height = int(input("Enter the height of the triangle: \n"))

array = [1]

for ch in range(height):
    print((str(array)[1:-1]))

    newarray = []
    newarray.append(array[0])
    for ch in range(len(array) - 1):
        (newarray.append(array[ch] + array[ch+1]))
    str(newarray.append(array[-1]))[1:-1]

    array = (newarray)
```

Comment: Simply replacing commas by spaces won't give you a very nice looking triangle. You need to do a bit more work if you want the triangle to look like the standard form of Pascal's triangle rather than flushed to the left.

Comment: The Triangle must output with left alignment and not necessarily like a triangle.

Comment: I see. For fun I encourage you to try to work out the needed spacing to get a more pleasing triangle. One of the best ways to learn as a student is to not merely solve the homework problems but to improve your solutions on your own.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use str.join before printing instead of str(array) and list comprehension to convert ints to strings ( or you can append strings to list initially), see example below:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
print(str(array))

print(''.join([str(item) for item in array]))
```

Comment: the string is iterable, that us the only significant similarities, in addition str is immutable whereas list is mutable.

Comment: @AdongOpolot great ! I would appreciate if you mark answer as accepted, so SO page for that question will be up to date  :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this `t = t.replace(',', ' ')`, This will replace your `','` into `' '` (spaces).

```
height = int(input("Enter the height of the triangle: \n"))

array = [1]

for ch in range(height):
    t = (str(array)[1:-1])
    t = t.replace(',', ' ')
    print(t)
    newarray = []
    newarray.append(array[0])
    for ch in range(len(array) - 1):
        (newarray.append(array[ch] + array[ch+1]))
    str(newarray.append(array[-1]))[1:-1]

    array = (newarray)
```